# GPG error (EXPKEYSIG) while on apt update on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apt

I was trying to update the apt repository on Ubuntu by running:

```
$sudo apt update
```

And I get the following error:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification.
The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
GPG error: https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64 
InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6ED91CA3AC1160CD NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
W: Failed to fetch https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/experimental/ubuntu18.04/amd64/InRelease 
The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 6ED91CA3AC1160CD NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
```

I googled this error and some blogs suggests to run

```
$sudo apt-key list
```

which I did and get:

```
pub   rsa4096 2016-06-24 [SC]
      AE09 FE4B BD22 3A84 B2CC  FCE3 F60F 4B3D 7FA2 AF80
uid           [ unknown] cudatools <cudatools@nvidia.com>

pub   rsa4096 2017-09-28 [SCE]
      C95B 321B 61E8 8C18 09C4  F759 DDCA E044 F796 ECB0
uid           [ unknown] NVIDIA CORPORATION (Open Source Projects) <cudatools@nvidia.com>
```

The following link [How to solve expired key](https://tecadmin.net/expired-key-expkeysig-with-apt/) suggests to run the following command with EXPKEYSIG, but I get the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 6ED91CA3AC1160CD
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.A0899nj0Vo/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 6ED91CA3AC1160CD
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

Really not sure how to resolve this? Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For solve your problem:

1. delete old key

   sudo apt-key del 6ED91CA3AC1160CD
2. delete repository info:

   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-runtime.list
3. reinit repository as write here https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/

   curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/gpgkey | 
   sudo apt-key add -
   distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
   curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-container-runtime/$distribution/nvidia-container-runtime.list | 
   sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-container-runtime.list
   sudo apt-get update

Answer (score -1):

For resolve this issue :-

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```